# How to use Unity to inject dependencies through factory?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Imagine I have something I will create through a factory:

```
public sealed class MyClass
    : IMyClass
{
    private IMyDao MyDao { get; set; }

    public MyClass(IMyDaoFactory factory)
    {
        MyDao = factory.MyDao;
    }
}
```

This might resolve through a service as:

```
public sealed class MyService
    : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMyClass myClass;

    public MyService(IMyDaoFactory factory)
    {
        myClass = new MyClass(factory);
    }
}
```

That's easy to wire up in Unity as:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>();
container.RegisterType<IMyDaoFactory, MyDaoFactory>();
container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

Noting the registration of MyClass, how can I set Unity up so it will automatically register and resolve through the factory? I.e. then I no longer need:

```
myClass = new MyClass(factory);
```

Only:

```
this.myClass = myClass; (passed through the constructor 
                         as IMyClass and resolved by Unity)
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to cast an Interface to a Concrete type considering an Interface exposes behavior?

Comment: It's an attempt to avoid more far-reaching refactoring. If I can do this, I can leave the whole data layer alone.

Comment: Nathan's answer seems OK; just register the appropriate dependencies and Unity will wire everything up for you.  e.g. IMyClass will have IMyDaoFactory injected into it.  Is there something else you need (perhaps with object lifetime)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the constructor of `MyService` to requiring a single instance of `IMyClass`; Unity should automatically fill in the gaps there and instantiate based on the type signatures.

```
public MyService(IMyClass _myClass)
{
    myClass = _myClass;
}
```

Although I'd also change the names up, but eh.

Comment: I use another container usually, so Unity had me scratching my head but once I worked out I could (as normal) worry about starting from the top of my dependency tree and work down from there, I was all set. Filling in the gaps, as it were.